# Kendo calendar year change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

I want to display a message when we navigate through calendar control in Kendo. But my condition is whenever we enter into new year I should display a message.

Ex: current month is July - 2013. when I navigate to next month Aug - 2013 --> In this case I don't want to display a message.

If we are in Dec - 2013, when I click next navigation button --> In this case I wanted to display a message like entered new year.

Same case for previous navigation also. When we are in Jan - 2013, if I press previous button it will enter into Dec - 2012 --> In this case also I wanted to display a message.

Is there any way to get it done?

Comment: Could you please accompany this with some code or a snippet in jsfiddle if possible. Your issue could get solved a lot easier.

Comment: Actually I'm not getting how to start.. calendar.bind("navigate", function () {
            
            
        });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the `navigate` handler as:

```
navigate: function () {
    var cur = this._current;
    var prev = this._previous;
    if (prev && cur && prev.getFullYear() !== cur.getFullYear()) {
        alert("year change");
    }
    this._previous = this._current;
}
```

What I do is get current date (`_current`) that is a reference date in current calendar view, then get its year and compare this with the previous date.

In addition, and since there is no `previous` date in a Calendar, I save it for using in the next navigation event.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jf2XK/